# learning javascript, functions

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying out this course for learning JavaScript and it was doing well until this assignment.

I must create an input field where the user can input an amount, (say euros) and when hitting enter, the value will be stored, and the second value that the user enters will be added and shown in a different input field.

I am not that far in the course so I only use functions, no arrays or whatever. I also need to make a function that tests if the input is numbers. Not anything else.

So I was thinking for the html part:

```
<form id="formulier">    
<p>Voer hier uw bedrag in en druk op Enter:</p>
<input type="text" id="input" onchange="calc()">

<p>Uitkomst:</p>
<input type="text" id="output"><br>
<button type="button" id="berekenBTW" onclick="calcBTW()">Bereken BTW</button>
<button type="button" id="reset" onclick="herstel()">Reset</button>
<br>
<p id="resBTW"></p>
</form>
```

But i cant think of a way to make the function like it would:

- check if its a value,
- if no, alert message
- if yes show it in output (and clear the input field)
- if user inserts new number, check again and add it to the first! and so on...

Then I need to make a button to calc the tax on the number, say 21% and show result a P and the reset.

I had this, but I don't think it makes any sense.

```
//after hitting enter

function calc(){
    var berekendeWaarde = document.getElementById("input");
    document.getElementById("output") =
        omzetter(berekendeWaarde).toFixed(2) + " euro.";
}
//the course says i must use an eventhandler and function handler so that why i do it this way
function omzetter(som)
{
    var x=som.value;
    var check=/^[0-9]+$/;
    if (x.match(check))
    {
        alert("Must input numbers");
        return false;
    }
    else{
        var x = SOMETHING; //so now the value is checked and its a correct number? then show it or add it to the prev value?
    }
}

//reset functie
function herstel() {
    document.getElementById("formulier").reset()
}
```

I really hope someone could help me.

Comment: Post the code here - https://jsfiddle.net/ I will take a look.

Comment: First of all, this line: `document.getElementById("output") = omzetter(berekendeWaarde).toFixed(2) + " euro.";` doesn't make sense. The left side of the equals grabs the element, but it sounds like what you want is to change the **_value_** of the element. That should be `document.getElementById("output").value = omzetter(berekendeWaarde).toFixed(2) + " euro.";`. Assuming that `output` is another input field. If it's not, then use: `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = omzetter(berekendeWaarde).toFixed(2) + " euro.";`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Burner/hxgb109c/

Thanks for taking the time..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Burner/hxgb109c/9/

i think it's this link. I'm not so familliar with Jsfiddle.